# Scala: overloading methods based on provided type

Tags: scala, api-design

Consider a simple object that serves as a storage for some cohesive data discriminated by type. I want it to have an API which is:

- consistent and concise;
- compile-time safe.

I can easily provide such API for saving objects by using *overloading*:

```
object CatsAndDogsStorage {
  def save(key: String, cat: Cat): Future[Unit] = { /* write cat to db */ }
  def save(key: String, dog: Dog): Future[Unit] = { /* save dog to Map */ }
  /* other methods */
}
```

But I cannot find a good way to declare such methods for loading objects. Ideally, I would want something like this:

```
// Futures of two unrelated objects
val catFuture: Future[Cat] = CatsAndDogsStorage.load[Cat]("Lucky")
val dogFuture = CatsAndDogsStorage.load[Dog]("Lucky")
```

I'm fairly new to Scala, but I know that I have these options (sorted from the least preferred):

#### 1. Different method names

```
def loadCat(key: String): Future[Cat] = { /* ... */ }
def loadDog(key: String): Future[Dog] = { /* ... */ }
```

Not the most concise method. I dislike how if I decide to rename Cat to something else, I would have to rename the method too.

#### 2. Runtime check for provided class

```
def load[T: ClassTag](key: String): Future[T] = classTag[T] match {
  case t if t == classOf[Dog] => /* ... */
  case c if c == classOf[Cat] => /* ... */
}
```

This one gives the desired syntax, but it fails in runtime, not compile time.

#### 3. Dummy implicits

```
def load[T <: Cat](key: String): Future[Cat] = /* ... */
def load[T <: Dog](key: String)(implicit i1: DummyImplicit): Future[Dog]
```

This code becomes nightmare when you have a handful of types you need to support. It also makes it quite inconvenient to remove those types

#### 4. Sealed trait + runtime check

```
sealed trait Loadable
case class Cat() extends Loadable
case class Dog() extends Loadable

def load[T <: Loadable: ClassTag](key: String): Future[T] = classTag[T] match {
  case t if t == classOf[Dog] => /* ... */
  case c if c == classOf[Cat] => /* ... */
}
```

This has the advantage of 2) while preventing user from asking anything besides Dog or Cat. Still, I would rather not change the object hierarchy. I can use [union types](http://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) to make the code shorter.

---

So, the last solution is okay, but it still feels hack-ish, and maybe there is another known way which I just cannot figure out.

Comment: I think you should check [Type Classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html), which is a commonly used pattern for type driven generics specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having functions with sligthly different name doing similar work but for differents type doesn't seem bad for me.

If you really want to have a facade API dispatching according the type you can use typeclasses.

```scala
trait SaveFn[T] extends (T => Future[Unit]) {}

object SaveFn {
  implicit object SaveDog extends SaveFn[Dog] { def apply(dog: Dog): Future[Unit] = ??? }

  implicit object SaveCat extends SaveFn[Dog] { def apply(cat: Cat): Future[Unit] = ??? }
}

object Storage {
  def save[T : SaveFn](in: T): Future[Unit] = implicitly[SaveFn[T]](in)
}
```

For the `.load` case:

```
trait LoadFn[T] extends (String => Future[T]) {}

object LoadFn {
  implicit object LoadDog extends LoadFn[Dog] { def apply(key: String): Future[Dog] = ??? }

  implicit object LoadCat extends LoadFn[Cat] { def apply(key: String): Future[Cat] = ??? }
}

object Storage {
  def load[T : LoadFn](key: String): Future[T] = implicitly[LoadFn[T]](key)
}
```

As for `.load` the inference cannot be found according the arguments as for `.save`, that's less nice to use: `Storage.load[Dog]("dogKey")`

Comment: Thanks for the example. I know it's nothing wrong with different names, I'm just exploring to get some fun with my pet project.